# How to assign the result of a conditional decision to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

The following code works fine:

```
    var styles = []
    if (state == 's1') {
        styles = ['inline-block', 'none', 'none']
    } else if (state == 's2') {
        styles = ['none', 'inline-block', 'none']
    } else if (state == 's3') {
        styles = ['none', 'none', 'inline-block']
    }
```

However in some languages we can make this more concise.  I would like to do something along the following lines:

```
    var styles = 
      if (state == 's1') {
          ['inline-block', 'none', 'none']
      } else if (state == 's2') {
          ['none', 'inline-block', 'none']
      } else if (state == 's3') {
          ['none', 'none', 'inline-block']
      }
```

Is there such a conditional assignment - or even better some kind of `match/case` - in javascript?

**Update** Lots of good answers - thanks!  Chose one seems closest to my original intent. But learnt a variety of aspects of javascript across many of them.

Comment: The closest i could think of would be ternary operator, but it's far from elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the conditions as a function

```
chooseStyle = (state) => {
    if (state == 's1') {
        return ['inline-block', 'none', 'none']
    } else if (state == 's2') {
        return ['none', 'inline-block', 'none']
    } else if (state == 's3') {
        return ['none', 'none', 'inline-block']
    }
}

var styles = chooseStyle(state)
```

Or even better if you use a `switch` instead:

```
chooseStyle = (state) => {
    switch(state) {
        case 's1':
            return ['inline-block', 'none', 'none']
        case 's2':
            return ['none', 'inline-block', 'none']
        case 's3':
            return ['none', 'none', 'inline-block']
        default:
            return ['inline-block', 'none', 'none'] // return the default styles you want, here I choose the styles of 's1'
    }
}
```

Comment: You function does not returns anythings. The result will always be `undefined`.

Comment: This looks so far actually closest to my original intent

Answer (score 2):

You could take an array of `states` and map either `'inline-block'` for a value at this index or `'none'`.

```js
const
    order = ['s1', 's2', 's3'],
    getStyles = state => order.map(v => v === state ? 'inline-block' : 'none');

console.log(...getStyles('s1'));
console.log(...getStyles('s2'));
console.log(...getStyles('s3'));
```

Comment: Not sure how the `v === state` makes this work - can you elaborate?

Comment: `v` is an item of `order` and if the value at this position is the wanted one, then it takes `'inline-block'` or `'none'` by using a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: ah got it: i was not thinking along collections manipulation lines

Answer (score 1):

Like many languages whose syntax is patterned after C, JavaScript has conditional expressions (aka "tertiary") that can be used for simple `if-then-else` conditions.

```
condition ? true-value : false-value
```

You can nest these for multiple cases, but it tends to become unreadable.

```
var styles = state == 's1' ? ['inline-block', 'none', 'none'] :
    (state == 's2' ? ['none', 'inline-block', 'none'] : ['none', 'none', 'inline-block']);
```

There's no analogous expression form of `case`. But you could use an object:

```
const style_mappings = {
    "s1": ['inline-block', 'none', 'none'],
    "s2": ['none', 'inline-block', 'none'],
    "s3": ['none', 'none', 'inline-block']
};
var styles = style_mappings[state];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a mapping object:

```
const styleMap = {
  s1: ['inline-block', 'none', 'none'],
  s2: ['none', 'inline-block', 'none'],
  s3: ['none', 'none', 'inline-block'],
};

const styles = styleMap[state];
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have anything *exactly* like that, but one solution which gets pretty close is to store the results in an object/dictionary and call it with the state you want:

```js
const styles = {
  's1': ['inline-block', 'none', 'none'],
  's2': ['none', 'inline-block', 'none'],
  's3': ['none', 'none', 'inline-block']
}
console.log(`s1: ${styles['s1']}`)
console.log(`s2: ${styles['s2']}`)
console.log(`s3: ${styles['s3']}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `switch` statement in JavaScript to accomplish this. Your code would be something like this

```js
var styles = ['none', 'none', 'none'];
switch (state) {
    case 's1':
        styles[0]='inline-block';
        break;
    case 's2':
        styles[1]='inline-block';
        break;
    case 's3':
        styles[2]='inline-block';
        break;
}
```

Comment: That still has  multiple explicit assignments .

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tenary javascript operator. So the code may look like so:

```
var styles = (state == 's1')? 
                        ['inline-block', 'none', 'none']:  (state == 's2')? 
                                                            ['none', 'inline-block', 'none']: (state == 's3')?
                                                                                              ['none', 'none', 'inline-block']:[];
```

Usage example:

```
Example 1:
var state = 's1'; 
console.log(styles);  //outputs [ "inline-block", "none", "none" ]
Example 2: 
var state = 's2'; 
console.log(styles);  //outputs [ "none", "inline-block", "none" ]
Example 3: 
var state = 's3'; 
console.log(styles);  //outputs [ "none", "none", "inline-block" ]
Example 4: 
var state = 's'//a state without a match
console.log(styles);  //outputs []
```